# How to slice some specific value in tensorflow by fixing step just like in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code I want to slice [[[3,30]]]. Can I perform numpy like slicing in tensorflow?

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],[[3, 31, 30], [4, 40, 4]],[[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]])
    s =tf.slice(t, begin=[1,0,0],size=[1,1,3])
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    print(t.shape)
    print(sess.run(s))
```

Comment: Have you tried doing numpy-like slicing in tensorflow?

Comment: Yes I tried it didn't work. I tried somethin like tf.slice(t, begin=[1,0,0],size=[1,1,2] ) but prints [[[3,31]]] but i want to print [[[3,30]]]

Comment: It is most likely be a mistake in your parameter, since you are getting the correct format, but the wrong value. Please try around with the parameters.

Comment: Can you please correct my misake?Because if I mention size=[1,1,2] it should give me 3,31. How to get [[[3,30]]]

Answer (score 1):

You can modified it slightly using [`tf.strided_slice()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) instead of `tf.slice()`

```
s = tf.strided_slice(t, begin=[1,0,0],end=[2,1,3],strides=[1,1,2])
```

The `end` is the value of `size` parameter + `begin` parameter. While `strides` describes whether to skip any element in every iteration while slicing (`1` means not skipping anything, `2` means skip 1 element, etc). Use `1, 1, 2` to skip 1 element in every iteration, which will skip the 2th, 4th, etc. This will give you `[[[3, 30]]]` instead of `[[[3, 31, 30]]]`